# copying few values in a row and pasting it multiple times in the same row in excel using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am very new to VBA.I know its a basic doubt but couldnt find the solution anywhere. I am trying to copy 24 (A1:A24)values and paste it number of times in (A25:A8760).I am able to copy a single value and paste it number of times.I couldnt do it for multiple values.

```
Sub Macro1()

Range("a1").Select
Selection.Copy

Range("a2:a30").Select

ActiveSheet.Paste     

End Sub
```

How do i do it if i multiple values?

```
Sub Macro1()

Range("a1:a24").Select
Selection.Copy
```

Now i need to paste the above 24 values to (A25:A8760) continously?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first I thought this: `Range("A1:A24").Copy Range("A25:A8760")` or `Range("A25:A8760").Value = Range("A1:A24").Value` should work. However it doesn't, because above solutions copy only in "used" part of the sheet.

Then I come up with following solution (copies only values):

```
With Range("A25:A8760")
    .Formula = "=A1"
    .Value = .Value
End With
```

**UPD:**

this code works:

```
Range("A25:A8760").Value = ""
Range("A1:A24").Copy Range("A25:A8760")
```

**Notes:**

I used `Range("A25:A8760").Value = ""` to make this range to be part of `UsedRange` (otherwise line `Range("A1:A24").Copy Range("A25:A8760")` would copy only in "used" part of the sheet)

Comment: what you expect it should copy?

Comment: `them` - what exactly you wnat to copy? As per your original question, `Now i need to paste the above 24 _values_ to (A25:A8760) continously` - and my code copies exactly 24 values and paste them continously in A25:A8760

Comment: i just dont get what the 'formula' does?

Comment: @vinothmannan, see my **UPD** part, I think it should solve your problem (it doesn't use loop)

Comment: `Formula` just add formula in cells, but then `.Value=.Value` rewrites formula results with values. However I found better solution - see my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

The following will copy and past 364 times...

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim i As Integer

Range("A1:A24").Select
Selection.Copy
For i = 1 To 364
    Range("A" & 1 + i * 24).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
Next i
End Sub
```